# Flag automatically changes it's value from 0 to 1

Tags: android, flags

I just experienced a weird behavior of flag. I'm writing an application in **android** where I needed to use a flag to check whether the alarm is fired or not. Initially it's set to 0 and once the alarm is fired it should change it's value to 1.

I know I should create a flag with `int` data type but I created with `String` though and set it's value to 0.

```
String flag = "0";
```

I stored the flag in each row of **sqlite** database having details of alarm.

When the alarm notifies the user of the task, the flag **automatically changes it's value from 0 to 1**. How is this possible? My flag has **`String`** data type and I haven't even set it's value to `1` when when alarm is fired. How it changes the value automatically?

**EDIT :**

If I create a variable **`guard`** instead of `flag` and initialize it's value to `no` then it's not changing after the alarm is rang.

```
String guard = "no";
```

This value does not get changed automatically after the user is notified. Then how the value of flag gets changed itself?

Comment: Impossible to answer based on the information provided, but trust me, your logic is not doing what you think it does...

Comment: I guess the same it should not change it's value but IT DOES!!

Comment: @jangroth I just want to change value of flag once the alarm is rang, I want to it manually but flag changes the value itself once the alarm is rang. Hard to believe but it's true man